# Markdown confuses @username in comment replies

Tags: support, comments, markdown

Earlier on SO, a reply was posted to a comment I made on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952216/delegating-into-private-parts/2952420#2952420).  My username in the reply was italicised and I didn't get any notification for it, which I assume is because of the letter-for-letter match that comment replies use.  If my guess is right, should the comment reply system ignore markdown for the purposes of matching usernames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is just a user oddity. For some reason that user formatted the comment as

```
*@Niall C.:* I'm not sure that the distinction between accessibility...
```

In such cases (never seen one before) the user is simply not following the standard formatting convention, so it can't be expected to work.

Comment: Lol, users can expect ANYTHING to work. @♦

Comment: Gotta love those squirrely edge cases.  Thanks.