# Am I seeing things?

Tags: discussion, comments, display-names

Yesterday, I was browsing MSO and I was looking at a comment thread. The `@nickname` syntax was in bold text. I thought that was pretty cool, then by some bizarre stroke of chance, the next question I happened to see was [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65333/).

I figured they just rolled out a change to highlight usernames, but it was only that one question I saw it on. I don't remember what question it was.

Were people in that thread intentionally **bolding** the replied username? I don't think it was unless comments in bold have a slightly dark-grey color instead of black. (Edit: they do! But I can't get the `@` to not be bold while being next to the username, which is what I saw it like... I think...)

Was it just a strange coincidence that happened to me? Did anything actually happen or is everything I know a lie?

Comment: **@Corey** testing 1... 2... 3...

Comment: I didn't hear the `3` can you repeat?

Comment: **@ring0** 3, [over.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KJCfUm21BsI)

Comment: Here's your quick test. If that ain't bold for you, then everything is just a strange coincidence and everything you ever knew was a lie.

Comment: I give up I keep forgetting the syntax for links in comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sometimes bold an @reference that's buried in a text meant for everyone. To make the more directed part of the comment stand out.

Alternatives include:

1. Not writing comments long enough to bury things. This is probably the best option, but I break my own rules...
2. Writing a separate comment. This is the way to go if the two sections are unrelated.
3. Trusting the notification system to get their attention.

Comment: Once upon a time: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52057/146318.  Does markdown in @username work now?

Comment: Well lets see, **@Niall**. You tell me. I mean, I image that making *only* the name bold will break (asterixes between the at-thingy and the name afterall), but I usually bold the whole reference.

Comment: I didn't get a notification envelope, and there's nothing in my Responses tab